# can't play audio File with JMF

Tags: java, eclipse, jmf

I have a problem with playing an MP3 file with JMF, it displays the following error :

```
Error: 
Unable to realize com.sun.media.amovie.AMController@80669d Exception in thread "main"

javax.media.CannotRealizeException at javax.media.Manager.blockingCall(Manager.java:2005) at
javax.media.Manager.createRealizedPlayer(Manager.java:528) at tp.Main.main(Main.java:44) 
Error value: 80070020
```

here is my code :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoPlayerException, CannotRealizeException, MalformedURLException, IOException, URISyntaxException {


        Fenetre F1 = new Fenetre();
        F1.setVisible(true);

        InputStream is = Main.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data/gmu.mp3");
        File temp=File.createTempFile("temp", ".mp3");
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(temp);
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            os.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        final Player p=Manager.createRealizedPlayer(temp.toURI().toURL());

        p.start();
        while(true){
            if(p.getMediaTime().getSeconds()==p.getDuration().getSeconds()){
                p.stop();
                p.setMediaTime(new Time(0));
                p.start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

normally it works If I don't use the InputStream, and use simply

```
File f =new File(Main.class.getResource("/data/gmu.mp3").getFile());
final Player p=Manager.createRealizedPlayer(temp.toURI().toURL());
```

but this way It doesn't work when I pack my JAR file, so I'm trying to use InputStream, the aim is to make a JAR with a WORKING music

Comment: I can recommend using JLayer. Not only does it work but it's easy to use.

Comment: I can't find how to know the current time of the Audio file and its duration in order to use them Like in the loop in my question, can you help me ?

Comment: Use JAudioTagger. Take a look at this to see how easy it is to get the track length using JAudioTagger: https://javaextreme.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/get-the-time-duration-of-an-audio-file-mp3/

Comment: thanx, it is, what about the current time of an Audio file ?

Comment: You should know also that I get errors when I try to Export it in JAR

Comment: Try wrapping the `InputStream` in a buffered stream.  AFAIR both Java Sound and JMF require a buffered stream. On the other hand, I thought they produced a different, more specific error than seen above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I just had to convert my MP3 file to WAV and it worked !!! I don't know why the player exception was caught with the MP3 temporary file but nothing goes wrong with WAV. this is not really the answer I sought since the WAV files takes a lot more space but at least it works.

I also tried OGG format, which makes the same problem of MP3 ...

any other answer, suggestion, or discussion is welcome.